# accessing junk folder of hotmail with htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit, hotmail

I want to access junk folder of hotmail account with htmlUnit in java as it seems that htmlunit supports javascript. With the following code I could access the inbox folder but from it I want to get the junk folder. I found that "junk" displayed on the left side of the page is a label. So I am trying to access the label and then want to click on it. But I am not able to access the "junk" label from the HtmlPage. Html code of junk label looks like below.

```
<span class="FolderLabel">
Junk
<span style="display:none;">
(
<span class="count"></span>
)
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

and following is the code I use to get junk folder:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.w3c.dom.Node;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNodeList;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlLabel;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;



public class TesthtmlUnit {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
     {
         final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            // Get the first page
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf");
            webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

            final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("f1");

            final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("SI");
            final HtmlTextInput uname = form.getInputByName("login");
            final HtmlPasswordInput pwd = form.getInputByName("passwd");
            // Change the value of the text field
            uname.setValueAttribute("emailid@hotmail.com");
            pwd.setValueAttribute("pwd");

            HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
            //System.out.println(page2.asXml());

            HtmlAnchor inbox = (HtmlAnchor) page2.getAnchorByHref("http://mail.live.com/?rru=inbox");
            page2 = (HtmlPage) inbox.click();
            //System.out.println(page2.asXml());

            //CLICK ON JUNK LABEL
          //here I want access label "junk" from page2 


            webClient.closeAllWindows();
     }

}
```

Anybody has idea how to click on junk folder ? I went through methods provided by htmlpage but could not find a way to do it.

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks.